# Leaking single handle faucet

Tags: faucet, leaking

I’m looking for guidance to access the cartridge of a leaking single handle bathroom faucet. It has no visible markings on it to determine manufacturer. I see how to remove the handle but question the 2 metal rings which are part of the faucet. Do these need to be removed to access the cartridge? If so, how.

I’ve attached 2 pictures to highlight them, one with red arrow and one with yellow arrow. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any chance of posting a pic or two that shows it zoomed out a bit for context?

Comment: I added additional picture Gnicko..  thx